# How use vim on a binary file?

Tags: vim, binary

`vim -b` is documented as

> -b   Binary mode.  A few options will be set that makes it  pos‐sible to edit a binary or executable file.

but that does not work for me.  For example

`echo "Unicode ☺☻☼☽☾☿♀♁♂♃♄♅♆♇♈♉♊♋♌♍" > testfile`

will store many bytes having the high bit set (assuming a UTF-8 terminal).  `od -a -t x1 testfile` confirms that.

But `vim -u NONE -b testfile` displays the Unicode characters, not the raw bytes.  So it is not actually possible to edit arbitrary binary data.

What's wrong?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong?

Making wild assumptions.

First, the following sentence doesn't imply *at all* that your file will be opened in some magic `xxd`-like hex editor mode:

> A few options will be set that makes it possible to edit a binary or executable file.

All you can get from that sentence is that you can "edit a binary or executable file", not that you get access to its ones, zeroes, and hexes.

Second, "a few options" is pretty vague. So digging a bit would seem like a good idea. `:help -b` says the following:

```
Binary mode.  File I/O will only recognize <NL> to separate
lines.  The 'expandtab' option will be reset.  The 'textwidth'
option is set to 0.  'modeline' is reset.  The 'binary' option
is set.  This is done after reading the vimrc/exrc files but
before reading any file in the arglist.  See also
|edit-binary|.
```

which, again, makes no promise whatsoever about editing ones, zeroes, or hexes.

I won't paste the content of the linked `:help edit-binary` but it doesn't make that kind of claim either.

So we are left with your file, which is a text file, not a binary file. It should be no surprise that your text editor treats its content as text.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to type any byte value if Ctl- and Meta- keys work as in days of yore.  Ctrl-@ through Ctrl-_ for 0x00-0x1F, regular ascii for 0x20-0x7E, DEL for 0x7f, and Meta-(the same) for 0x80-0xFF.   Presumably in vim preceded by ^V to be read literally.  I don't think that was such a wild assumption.   But it seems like vim doesn't allow that.